# How to remove compact layout from object?

Tags: lightning, compact-layout

I have a compact layout on an object that I previously used, but no longer use as I reverted to the System Default layout:

[image]

I naively assumed that removing it would be simple to remove, either through an option on the context menu button on the right, or through a delete button on the edit screen. Unfortunately this is not the case.

How can I remove this redundant layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the custom compact layout by using the delete button on the layout page. In your case, You have created a custom compact layout and it can  be deleted.

[image]

Note:-Default compact layout cannot be deleted.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I was going onto the Edit screen direct from the context menu, without ever clicking on the layout itself.

Comment: @John It happens. We are humans:)